# RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant") on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running django on Elastic Beanstalk and after pushing a new version of the app I'm getting a 500 internal server error.

The logs show this:

```
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
 RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
 mod_wsgi (pid=21994): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=21994): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/python/current/app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
```

Any advice on debugging this? My attempts to understand it/google it so far have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

it normally happens when the interpreter failed to load the source(provided you had it running) or (if you are deploying) it points out to a configuration issue mostly related to the number of threads that try to load the same interpreter.

I would suggest you to do a hard restart of the service that runs the app. This will most likely solve it. If the error persists check your wsgi configuration.

Comment: Thanks @t.stv - it turns out this wasn't ultimately caused by the code, but by a database problem. After forcibly migrating the database I re-built the app and all is well.

Comment: @goose could you please tell more about the database problem?